# Want to print out the double digits numbers, only when tens digit is higher than units digi, Java

Tags: java, if-statement

So basically I want to print out the double digits numbers (10-99), only when tens digit is higher than units digits, I created two if’s statements and the JOptionPane that I can input only two digits numbers, when trying less than 10 or more than 99 I created an MessageDialog. For example (91, 47, 68, 21), I want to print only “91, 21”

int numbers;

```
    while (true) {
        numbers = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ENTER THE NUMBERS BETWEEN 10 AND 99"));
        if (numbers >= 10 && numbers <= 99) {
            System.out.print(numbers + " ");
        } else if (numbers != 99) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WRONG NUMBER!");
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Please include your current Java code, as I suspect you have already done some work here.

Comment: I’m not at home at the moment cannot do it right now

Comment: ok i paste my code

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this via a `for` loop with the help of the modulus operator:

```java
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=10; i < 100; ++i) {
    if ((i / 10) % 10 > i % 10) {
        nums.add(i);
    }
}

System.out.println(nums);
```

This prints:

```
[10, 20, 21, 30, 31, 32, 40, 41, 42, 43, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,
 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76,
 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
```

Comment: What if I want to enter the numbers by myself without an array or list, the if statement gonna be the same I bet?